# How to find the second lowest lists into a nested list by their second value?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nested-lists

Here is given a nested list:

```
nl = [['Harsh', 20], ['Beria', 20], ['Varun', 19], ['Kakunami', 19], ['Vikas', 21]]
```

Now I have to find the second lowest lists into the nested list by their second value. And append the second lowest lists into another list.

So the output should be:

```
['Harsh', 20], ['Beria', 20]
```

I wrote the following code but it doesn't work:

```
nl = [['Harsh', 20], ['Beria', 20], ['Varun', 19], ['Kakunami', 19], ['Vikas', 21]]

result=[]

temp=max(nl, key=lambda x: x[1])

largest, larger = temp[1], temp[1]
for num in nl:
    if num[1] < largest:
        largest, larger = num[1], largest
    elif num[1] < larger:
        larger = num[1]
        result.append(larger)
print(result)
```

Comment: Why it doesnt work? errors?

Comment: No error..it doesn't generates the correct output. It gives [20,19] only.

Comment: That is exactly [this question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) from HackerRank.com
Category/path: Hackerrank.com -> Practice -> Python -> Basic Data Types -> Nested Lists

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get the `min` of the total elements, filter using that valid then get min of remaining and keep elements equal to min of remaining:

```
from operator import itemgetter
# min of all elements
mn = min(nl, key=itemgetter(1))[1]

# remove elements equal to min
filtered = [x for x in nl if x[1] != mn]

# get min of remaining
mn_fil = min(filtered,key=itemgetter(1))[1]

# filter remaining
out = [x for x in filtered if x[1] == mn_fil]
print(out)

[['Harsh', 20], ['Beria', 20]]
```

Works for both your cases:

```
In [19]: nl = [['Prashant', 32], ['Pallavi', 36], ['Dheeraj', 39], ['Shivam', 40]]    
In [20]: from operator import itemgetter    
In [21]: mn = min(nl, key=itemgetter(1))[1]    
In [22]: filtered = [x for x in nl if x[1] != mn]    
In [23]: mn_fil = min(filtered,key=itemgetter(1))[1]    
In [24]: out = [x for x in filtered if x[1] == mn_fil]    
In [25]: out
Out[25]: [['Dheeraj', 36]]
```

Using a single for loop we remove all elements from the temp list if we find a lower element, if we find and equally lower one we append it:

```
mn = min(nl, key=itemgetter(1))[1]
temp = []
best = float("inf")
for ele in nl:
    if mn < ele[1] < best:
        best = ele[1]
        temp = []
        out.append(ele)
    elif ele[1] == best:
        temp.append(ele)
print(temp)
```

Comment: Your code is not giving the correct output for the test case nl = [['Prashant', 32], ['Pallavi', 36], ['Dheeraj', 39], ['Shivam', 40]] .It gives [['Dheeraj', 39]] .But the output should be: [['Pallavi',36]]

Comment: @AbdullahAlImran, sorry thought you wanted second highest, it works now

Comment: I think you didn't noticed that I asked for second lowest. Not second highest. I got the correct output after changing max into min. :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I did it by finding the second lowest value using a set and then selecting elements from the list with the same value.

```
#ordering by value
nl.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])

values_set = set()
for value in nl:
    values_set.add(value[1])

values_list = list(values_set)
#ordering
values_list.sort()
#getting second lowest values
lowest_values = [lowest for lowest in nl if lowest[1] == values_list[1] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
arr = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    arr1 = [name, score]
    arr.append(arr1)
arr.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
# print(arr)
# print(min(arr,key=lambda x:x[1]))
arr.remove(min(arr,key=lambda x:x[1]))
# print(arr)
minimum = min(arr,key=lambda x:x[1])
# print(minimum[1])
a=[]
minimum = minimum[1]
for i  in arr:
    if(i[1] == minimum):
        a.append(i[0])
a.sort()
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thank you for your time answering this question. Can you please give more details about your solution? Why is it better than the accepted answer? Comments should provide additional insights to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a handy little function that incorporates [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

> Return a list with the n largest elements from the dataset

---

```
import heapq
num = heapq.nlargest(2, [key for item, key in nl])[-1]
print [item for item in nl if item[-1] == num] #[['Harsh', 20], ['Beria', 20]]
```

Comment: Your code is not giving the correct output for the test case 
nl = [['Prashant', 32], ['Pallavi', 36], ['Dheeraj', 39], ['Shivam', 40]]

.It gives [['Dheeraj', 39]]

.But the output should be: [['Pallavi',36]]

Comment: How should it be Pallavi? 39 is the second largest after 40 not 36.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code. It works fine.

```
lst=[['Harry',37.21],['Berry',37.21],['Tina',37.2],['Akriti',41],['Harsh',39]]
names=[]
lowest = lst[0].__getitem__(1)
second_lowest=0
for l in lst:
    if l[1] < lowest:
        second_lowest = lowest
        lowest = l[1]
    elif l[1]<=second_lowest:
        second_lowest=l[1]
for l in lst:
    if l[1]==second_lowest:
        names.append(l[0])


print(lowest)
print(second_lowest)
print(names)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    n = []
    s = []
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        n.append(name)
        score = float(input())
        s.append(score)
        
data = [[x,y] for x,y in zip(n,s)]

min_marks = min([x[1] for x in data])

filtered_data = [d for d in data if d[1] != min_marks]

sec_min = min([x[1] for x in filtered_data])

students_with_sec_min_marks = sorted([d[0] for d in filtered_data if d[1] == sec_min])

for s in students_with_sec_min_marks:
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lst = []
    names = []
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        lst.append([name, score])
     
    lowest = max(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
    second_lowest=0
    for l in lst:
        if l[1] < lowest:
            second_lowest = lowest
            lowest = l[1]
        elif l[1] < second_lowest and l[1] != lowest:
            second_lowest = l[1]
    for l in lst:
        if l[1] == second_lowest:
            names.append(l[0])  
    
    names.sort()
    for nm in names:
        print(nm)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code and it worked good:

```
records = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        records.append([name,score])
        records.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])
    minimum = min(records,key=lambda x:x[1])
    minimum = minimum[1]
    args = records.copy()
    
    for i in args:
        if(i[1] == minimum):
            records.remove(i)
        else:
            continue
    
    minimum = min(records,key=lambda x:x[1])
    minimum = minimum[1]
    a=[]
    for i  in records:
        if(i[1] == minimum):
            a.append(i[0])

    a.sort()
    for i in a:
        print(i)
```

This way, you will also be able to remove multiple same lowest scores if they exist. Running it without `copy()` and working on the original list causes the loop to miss the several same lowest scores.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
students=[]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        students.append([name,score])
    
            
students.sort(key=lambda x:x[1]  )  
students.remove(min(students,key=lambda x:x[1] ))
names=[]
score=students[0][1]
for student in students:
    if student[1]==score:
        names.append(student[0])
names.sort()
for each in names:
    print(each)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Your example can be simplified into this:

```
second_lowest = sorted(set(v[1] for v in nl))[1]
result = [v for v in nl if v[1] == second_lowest]
print(result) # [['Harsh', 20], ['Beria', 20]]
```

I use set of your values to find second, unique lowest value.
Than having this file, find elements in nl that match the found value.

Comment: how does `list(set(v[1] for v in nl))[1]` find the values in any order?

Comment: output of `print(set(v[1] for v in nl))` is `set([19, 20, 21])`. So just take second value, which will be second lowest.

Comment: Yes but there is absolutely no guarantee of that order, why do you think there will be?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham is correct. `set` does not guarantee that the set elements will be sorted.

Comment: Yep. you right. I added sorting of the set to be sure its sorted:-) Got confused with a set in c++.

Comment: Your code doesn't generates correct output at all. Check the test case:  nl = [['Prashant', 32], ['Pallavi', 36], ['Dheeraj', 39], ['Shivam', 40]] .Your code gives [['Shivam', 40]] as output. But the output should be [['Dheeraj', 39]].

Thank you for your try.

Can anyone give me the correct solution?

Comment: `[['Dheeraj', 39]].` is second largest, not second lowest. My code gives `['Pallavi', 36]` which is correct. Maybe you have code before edit pointed out by @PadraicCunningham.

Answer (score -1):

I have come across similar kind of problem and after referring this page I got some ideas and able to solve it.

```
nl = [['Harsh', 20], ['Beria', 20], ['Varun', 19], ['Kakunami', 19], ['Vikas', 21]]

second = max(nl, key= lambda x: x[1])[1]
first = min(nl, key= lambda x: x[1])[1]
    
for i in range(len(nl)):
    if nl[i][1] <= second and nl[i][1] != first:
        second = nl[i][1]
    
for i in range(len(nl)):
    if second == nl[i][1]:
        print(nl[i], end=", ")
```

Comment: This answer would be better with some explanation, especially how it differs from the other answers.